# R - Adding title in forecast ggAcf plot

Tags: r

I am using the following code to plot the autocorrelation function:

```
library("forecast")
test <- residuals_1
test
ggAcf(test)

> test
 [1] -0.007489643 -0.028647349 -0.056445887 -0.018056057  0.075785812  0.102454147  0.056657957
 [8]  0.089838858 -0.047288260 -0.144325054 -0.221173486 -0.285704817 -0.105637189 -0.057585221
[15]  0.289363355  0.232136048  0.060862228  0.088730220  0.083025121  0.045737330  0.085514892
[22]  0.068116717 -0.076698895 -0.071536686 -0.036157361 -0.067018577 -0.136408034 -0.092150816
```

How can I add some title in the graph? Which command should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, here is the solution using the `main` argument:

```
ggAcf(residuals_1,main='Text for title')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
acf <- forecast::ggAcf(rnorm(test))

acf + ggtitle("Autocorrelation Function ACF") + xlab("Lag") + ylab("ACF")
```